# Installing USB driver for XIAOMI Android Studio

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb, usb-drivers, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

I read the [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) page that describes how to connect your device to Android Studio that allows you to install and run your apps on your device. But I have a Xiaomi RedMi 2, and the [link](http://www.xiaomi.com/c/driver/index.html) that they provide that allows you to download the [OEM USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) for my device is all in Chinese. How do I install the required driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the google translation: hope it works for you.

> [Abstract] to install the driver, is the beginning of our wire brush,
>   brush machine process is a very important step, but also a lot of
>   local friends easily qualify problem areas. Just use a USB cable can
>   not be achieved mobile phone and computer information exchange, but
>   also need to drive.
>
> Click here to download the millet phone drivers:
>   http://bigota.d.miui.com/tools/xiaomi_usb_driver.rar
>
> Install the driver, is the beginning of our wire brush, brush machine
>   process is a very important step, but also a lot of local friends
>   easily qualify problem areas. Just use a USB cable can not be achieved
>   mobile phone and computer information exchange, but also need to
>   drive.
>
> First of all, I do not recommend to install the phone drivers to use
>   wizard-driven software or pea pods, millet has provided official
>   drivers, in my opinion, this driver should be the most secure, but
>   with other software to install, simply by hardware identification to
>   select the drive, and the identification is correct or not can not be
>   100% sure, this process is not artificially controlled, equivalent to
>   drive right to choose to install a mindless software, I think it is
>   not so reliable .
>
> Driver installation is a wire brush and turn on USB debugging to
>   operate the first step of the phone, very important, the situation is
>   a lot of brush machine failures are caused by improper installation of
>   the drive, I hope you pay attention to drive installation. I trust
>   that, in the Device Manager under the windows of the hardware manager
>   millet choose to install the official driver.
>
> [Recognizes three modes] In the boot state, after off USB debugging
>   connect the phone to a computer, mobile phone should be recognized as
>   a portable device, and the USB debugging turned on, is recognized as
>   androidphone and portable devices in fastboot mode is identified as
>   fastbootinterface.
>
> Under fastboot mode USB Debugging on mode USB Debugging OFF mode
>
> [Specific installation steps] To turn on USB debugging mode, win7
>   system installation drive, for example, the installation steps as
>   follows:
>
> 1. USB debugging turned on the phone, connected to a computer, but right-click "Computer" (XP is "My Computer") → "Management" → Device
>      Manager
> 2. Right "android" → "Update Driver Software" → "Browse my computer for driver"
> 3. millet phone to find driving compressed file, right -
>      "pressure to the current folder", select millet phone drivers extract
>      the folder "xiaomi_usb_driver", the next step
> 4. jumped a security warning, click "Install this driver software"
> 5. and then is done [Driver information] Driver installation, in fact, is
>      to copy the driver files to the system folder, determine whether the
>      driver is installed properly, you can view the information. Driver
>      information fastboot mode Driver information open USB debugging mode.
>      Close driver information USB debugging mode So far, my experience
>      sharing driver installation is over, we want to help the old and new
>      rice.
>
>    Click here to download the millet phone drivers:
>      http://bigota.d.miui.com/tools/xiaomi_usb_driver.rar

Answer (score 1):

Install [Mi PC Suite](http://pcsuite.mi.com/) instead, it will work.  It [automatically installs the drivers](http://www.technobuzz.net/install-android-usb-driver-xiaomi-devices/).